# jqGrid - column resize event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with jqGrid. I need to call a function when a column is resized. I have tried the following...

```
$grid = jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
    ...          
resizeStop: function(width, index) { 
        alert("resize column " + index + " to " + width " + "pixels"); 
    },
    ...
});
```

... but the event does not fire.

Am I missing something? Any ideas anyone?

Thanks!

Comment: You've got an error in that `alert`. Should be: `alert("resize column " + index + " to " + width + "pixels");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, found the problem.

The code was correct, but I had downloaded a version of jqGrid without jQuery UI addons enabled. I fixed it but downloading the complete version of jqGrid.